# Send email confirmation with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, devise

I have devise and omniauth installed for letting users sign up with their facebook account (this works).Now I want to send an email to an user when they have created an account with the facebook login functionality.

I am also using Actionmailer to send trigger based emails to users. Since I am using devise I don't have a create method in my user model to trigger the email, so I thought to make use of the standard functionality of devise to send out a confirmation email. I have added confirmable to the user model, but now i get the following error:

NameError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
undefined local variable or method `confirmed_at' for #

I don't understand the error message. For my perspective the devise gem is quite a black box and I don't see to which controller the error is referring to. Any help from someone who understands the devise gem better than I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you add the new column to the users table in the DB ?You might have to create the migration file and/or run `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error message is because the blackbox devise confirmation functionality uses fields that it assumes exist on the `User` model. This means that it assumes you have ensured the columns exist in the database for the users table. You need to do more than just add confirmable to the `User` model. You also need to add the migration for `confirmed_at` and then `rake db:migrate`.

Generate the migration:

```
rails g migration add_confirmable_to_devise
```

Make sure the contents of the migration match this:

```
class AddConfirmableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table(:users) do |t| 
      t.string   :confirmation_token
      t.datetime :confirmed_at
      t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      t.string   :unconfirmed_email
    end
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token, :unique => true 
  end
end
```

Then run your migration with `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: thanks for your response I have exectuted your post and now I get this error: undefined local variable or method `unconfirmed_email' for #<User:0x52fe9d8>. Do I need to add another field now?

Comment: Oh my mistake, yep you're right. I'll update my answer.

Comment: If you don't want to recreate the db then you'll have to generate another migration file and just add that one field `unconfirmed_email`. Otherwise you can just just update the `add_confirmable_to_devise` migration you just created and rerun the migrations.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have added the extra field and I don't get the error anymore. However, I don't receive any emails yet. I have set-up the actionmailer for dev and production using mailgun and this is working for other emails (not devise) but not for the confirmation email. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure offhand. Devise should be using actionmailer so it should work if other emails are working. I would check the rails log to make sure it looks like it's successfully firing the email. The issue is probably more easily solved by asking a new question.